# Azure DevOps Project SharePoint Portal: Document Repository

Tags: azure, sharepoint, azure-devops, devops

I have set up the Project in Azure DevOps successfully and need to set up a document repository for the project documents. I remember we had integration available between TFS and Sharepoint so I assume the same integration would be available in Azure also but unfortunately after going through so many resources still I could not find how can a Document Repository (SharePoint Site) be configured in Azure DevOps. If there is no SharePoint integration available then what is the way to achieve the same.

I thought of creating a SharePoint site in SharePoint online and mention the same URL in Project Portal settings but the challenge there is I do have the users from 2 different domain and SharePoint online would be associated with Organization Active directory so the users from other domain are not being added.

Comment: Hi, does my answer give you any help? Feel free to let me know the latest status about your puzzle.

Comment: Yes Merlin, Thanks for the reply. So when I would install this extension where exactly it would keep my files or where it would upload to? In order to upload my files, I need some repository. Which repository it would be?

Answer (score 2):

Until now, Azure Devops does not support integrate with SharePoint. But you can use an extension which named [SharePoint Files Uploader](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=projectumapsvsts.upload-sp-files-app) to achieve this.

[image]

In addition, **Azure Devops** just support backed with one **AAD** with the one domain. As workaround, you can invite these users who under other domain as guest in **AAD**. So that they can access the org successfully.

For integrate SharePoint with AzureDevops, you can raise one suggestion [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21).You can vote and add your comments for this suggestion. When there are enough communities vote and add comments for this feedback, the product team member will take this feedback seriously

Comment: SharePoint Files Uploader seems useful - but where is the documentation on how to use it?